# Problemas com modais

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, modal

Estou usando o [template](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/altair-admin-material-design-uikit-template/full_screen_preview/12190654) em Angular. Preciso abrir uma página dentro de um modal, para isso usei um código que foi sugerido pelo suporte do template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#conteudo2').on({
    'show.uk.modal': function () {
        $('#conteudo2').find('.modal-content').load("app/components/forms/regularView.html");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="uk-modal" id="conteudo2">
   <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
   <div class="uk-modal-header">teste</div>
   <div class="modal-content"></div>
   </div>
```

Porém, o resultado fica conforme a imagem, não inicializa os componentes, e dá um monte de erros, como poderia resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque não usa alguma lib de modal ao invés de usar Jquery?

Comment: pode me indicar alguma?

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que sua solucao esteja um pouco errada.

Como citado, ja que esta utilizando angularjs, um framework que tambem utiliza jQuery em seu codigo, existe certos pontos que deveria ficar atento ao utiliza-los simultaneamente.

O ideal seria, nunca utilizar um jQuery dentro de um controller, e ou sendo iniciado diretamenta na pagina alterando o DOM.

O jQuery pode ser melhor executado sem interefir na performance do angularJS quando utilizado dentro de uma diretiva dentro da funcao LINK e nao dentro do controller.

Acredito tambem que a melhor solucao pra ti neste caso ja que esteja utilizado angular, seria de utilizar alguma lib/module ou algo que esteja escrito em angularjs para nao ter nenhum tipo de interferencia ou algum possivel erro x.

Possivelmente algo esteja fora do ciclo de digest do angular, ou interferindo diretamente causando o erro.

Ou a chamada do modal, ou o template.

Acredito tambem que caso o componente da modal seja alguma biblioteca angular js, seu template deve seguir o mesmo padrao que o angular utiliza para renderiza-lo dentro da modal e exibir os dados corretamente.

Conforme ja citado nos comentarios, uma das possiveis solucoes seria utilizado o mais popular angula.bootstrap ou talvez procurar alguma outra seguindo os padroes do google como sugerido pelo seu screenshot.

LumX eh um framework de design de interfaces baseado no google material e tambem escrito em angularjs.

http://ui.lumapps.com/

A resposta eh um pouco grande, mas espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu desde que comecei a usar **AngularJs** deixei de usar **jquery**, o angular controla o DOM de uma forma muito mais intuitiva.

No exemplo do modal eu normalmente uso o do w3.css que é puro CSS, e com o AngularJS defino quando é que o modal abre através de um `ng-class` que alterna entre `display:none` e `display:block`.

```
<link href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel='stylesheet' type="text/css"></link>
<style>.show{display:block}</style>
// a class="w3-modal" tem a propriedade display:none por defeito.    

<button ng-click="abrirModal=true">Abrir Modal</button>
<div class="w3-modal" ng-class="{'show':abrirModal}">
  <div class="w3-modal-content">
   <button ng-click="abrirModal=false">Fechar Modal</button>
   <h1>Conteúdo Aqui</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```